# Android 11 bypass the permissions of "allow only while using the app"

Tags: android, android-permissions

I trying to develop an app that can take photos in the background. This app can prevent mobile phones from being stolen. If be stolen, the phone will send back photos and location.
I started an android service to receive the command from the user. The service can call android-camera2 to take pictures.
But the app I wrote doesn't work that It can only be allowed when it is used. Once the activity enters the background, it can't take photos. How can I solve this problem? I can modify the ROM of the android system. So are there any tips that can be provided?
thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question.

Comment: This is actually a good question I don't have the answer too. Since you are looking to do this at the ROM level it should be possible, but you will need to find the relative files and modify them. Start by cloning the AOSP, than trace the camera API through its source files. You may need to access some native functions. Good luck!